# If machine throws event log 5002 and it is not followed by the event 5004 I want to know that computer name

Tags: sql

there is a table with computer event logs, I am looking to get all computers that show event 5002 but only if that event is not followed by an event 5004, I can't seem to quite figure out how to query that

Comment: What does your question have to do with SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and a database tag.  And more information.  What if there is an intervening event, for instance?

Comment: Post the structure of your tables and the relationship between an element and the following element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please follow the suggestion you have been given (provide your data structure, sample data and desired output). Also use correct tag use SQL only if you use SQL to store your logs, otherwise, in this case, just a 'logging' tag would suffice